# Does W3 Total Cache work for child sites

Tags: wordpress

**Peace to all!**
I searched a lot on the web to find an answer to this question. Please help me.

In **wordpress multisite**, If I install **W3 Total Cache** on the **main site**, does **caching** work for all the **child sites**?
Also I observed that giving control of this plugin to the child site admins is a potential risk. So I don't want them to know in any way that this plugin is installed.

In a nutshell, I want to install this marvellous plugin globally on my site network **without** letting the **site admins having control over it.**

**Please help!**

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but network activation (until the next release) needs to be done an per site basis.

Comment: First of all thank you for designing such a good plugin.. . .Could you tell me when is the plugin arriving ? .... thanks